# Checking grammar of non-English text (NLP)

Tags: computational-linguistics, nlp, grammar, computer-science

I am writing a program that will take input from users in non-English languages (German, French, Spanish, Italian, and Portuguese) and will need to determine whether the input is grammatically correct. The majority of the coding will be done in Python, so I would like suggested tools to have a Python interface if possible.

I've found the Python NLTK which contains a grammar module. Their data includes English and Spanish grammars, but I am still in need of the other languages. Any help is greatly appreciated. Also, grammars for other languages are welcome, but the listed ones are the ones I will definitely need.

Comment: As far as I know, the NLTK grammars are Context-Free Grammars for parsing / generation rather than a module which checks grammar against some standard set of usage guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A long time ago, [LanguageTool](http://www.languagetool.org/) used to be usable with just OpenOffice. These days, they have a stand-alone version too. In contrast to NLTK, LanguageTool is made (and extended) with Java. I suppose you could use Jython.

AbiWord also has a grammar checking tool that is built using [Link Grammar](http://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/).  This was made with C.

Both tools support many languages.

Comment: Thanks for the help! LanguageTool seems to be exactly what I need. They've got an embedded server that I can set up and just send requests to since my code will be running as part of a web page.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at OpenNLP http://opennlp.apache.org/. It's in JAVA but it does have a parsing component. It is supposed to be available across languages but you may have to train it. Frankly, I haven't used it for anything myself so would be interested in hearing whether it is useful for an application like yours.

Comment: I took a quick look at OpenNLP, and while it seems pretty cool, I just need a simple way to check the grammar. Thank you for the help though.